# Selenium Key Press not working in Firefox

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, sendkeys

I'm building a web crawler package and I'm trying to do some key press using selenium. However, I find that keys like `Keys.SHIFT` or `Keys.CONTROL` doesn't work at all. But if I manually press them, they will work. 
I've tried both of lines of codes below, and neither of them worked.

```
ac.key_down(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.F2).key_up(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).perform()
elem1.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT+Keys.F2)
```

I was trying to open the developer tools in Firefox

Comment: provide the manual steps for this scenario ?

Comment: Hi, the manual step is just press shift and F2 at the same time in the browser and the dev tools will pop out

Answer (score 1):

Check this post https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/665 against your versions (browser, browser driver, selenium etc which are always sensible to include in any question), it could be a known bug with the geckodriver for the CONTROL key.

The post includes a work around of creating the chord in a different way, using:

```
List<CharSequence> keyWithModifiers = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
keyWithModifiers.add(Keys.CONTROL);
keyWithModifiers.add("a");
String ctrlA = Keys.chord(keyWithModifiers);
textFieldElem.sendKeys(ctrlA);
```

This approach worked for me using Selenium 3.7.1 Java bindings, gecko driver 0.18.0 (64 bit) and Firefox 57.0.2 - 59.0

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems mighty reasonable.

Comment: @zhiao Hope it helps. If it works for you please can you consider accepting this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To press shift&F2 keys use following code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(" Xpath loaction")).SendKeys(Keys.LeftShift);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(" Xpath loaction")).SendKeys(Keys.F2);
```

Comment: Hi, I wanna hit the two keys at the same time instead of one after another

Comment: Use this...And Let me know it is useful or not::String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CTRL, Keys.SHIFT);
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(selectAll);